# How to put exclude rule if property value contains specific value in search results

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint we have top right corner search box. From that results, I need to add rule for exclude peoples those have profile property value = "1". Per example

```
urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:WebEnabled
```

WebEnabled is the SSP profile property. Now results are pulling all users those have property value "0" or "1". Now I need exclude profile those have WebEnabled =1 value.

I added rule in scope. I don't know how to set value for that.

```
contentclass = urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:WebEnabled
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Add a Scope Rule page you'll find this text

> Enter the property restriction as a comparison of property to a value. All items matching the property query will be added to the scope. To make additional properties available for use in scopes, navigate to the managed properties list and select "Allow this property to be used in scopes" for the desired managed propertes.

So you'll need to find what Managed Property that belongs to and flip that bit so that you can use it in your scope rule.